# Increase maximum width of boxplots with facet_wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When generating boxplots with a facet_wrap, ggplot2 leaves a lot of space between the boxes. I would like to make them wider.

```
library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price)) +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap("color")
```

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQA8h.png)

I believe it's because it is leaving space in case it needs to plot combinations of factor levels that don't need to be plotted in each panel. To check this, I generated a similar plot with a new variable which is `cut` by `color`, plotted it on the x-axis, facet_wrapped by `color` with `scales = "fixed"`. It looks like the box widths are the same in both plots.

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds2 <- mutate(diamonds, CUTxCOLOR = paste(cut, color, sep = "."))
ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x = CUTxCOLOR, y = price)) +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap("color", scales = "fixed")
```

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8odK.png)

Any ideas about how to go about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width parameter in geom_boxplot should do the trick:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = .6, position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap("color")
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I'd just add that in ggplot2 v2.2.1.9000 the default "geom_boxplot" position is "dodge2". With width less than one, that actually makes the boxes smaller, and a width greater than 1 makes it so that the boxes don't align on the x axis. I had to specify `position = "dodge"`, but then it worked

Comment: This is because the default `preserve` argument is `"total"` for `position_dodge()` and `"single"` for `position_dodge2()` [ref](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2290). This works as well: `geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "total"))`